# How should I behave with questions asked under a tag when they are in fact about something unrelated to this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm regularly answering questions about accessibility.

From time to time, I see questions that have the accessibility tag, but have nothing to do with accessibility. The error is always the same, the author interprets "accessibility" like "access control", "access rights" or "being allowed to access".

As a reminder, the accessibility tag is described by:

> Accessibility seeks to make an application or website usable by everyone, including people with disabilities such as visual, auditory, ambulatory, or cognitive impairment.

Today's example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693747/how-to-restrict-access-to-anypoint-platform-public-url).

When I see this, I edit the question to remove the accessibility tag from it, since it's wrong, from my point of view.

Am I correct doing it?

Should I replace it with another tag? Which one?

Is there a way to tell authors that they chose a wrong tag and indicate them the right one?
For example, should I post a comment to explain it?

Comment: I think it's correct, and there is multiple tag that can replace it: [tag:.htaccess],[tag:access-rights],[tag:access-log], it just depend of the question

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely be removing tag(s) from a question when they are being used incorrectly. I think your edit note on that question is good and the author can see that.

Comment: There actually is guidance for this but it's in the description instead of the usage guidance.

Comment: Ah yes, that was one of my side questions: does the author see my edit reason ? Thank you to confirm that he does. So I assume then that commenting is completely optional. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah accessibility has nothing to do with that question, please continue your valiant endeavour.

Comment: That tag excerpt almost misses the point because of the truncation. IMHO it could just state "Make an application usable for people with disabilities". More is too much to read. Similarly, some of the other accessibility tags should get to point.

Comment: I do this often, removing/changing tags for inexperienced users is pretty normal really, you're overthinking it. If you have a better tag, use that one, otherwise just remove the wrong tags. Adding an explanation can be also done in the edit summary if you want.

Comment: I'd say it's worth noting that the user who misuses a tag is mostly harming his or herself. Mistagging is likely to lower the amount of good answers he or she gets, so hopefully that motivates those users to tag properly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

##### To directly answer the question in the title:

You did good. Misusing tags is a common phenomena and removing/retagging is the solution. You should always do your best to apply the most suitable tags instead of just removing a tag so that the question has better chances of landing on the right eyes.

As you mentioned in the question, you could of course comment on the question regarding the misuse of the tag, but that is unlikely to affect the larger-scale misuse by other users who will not see this comment, only educate the OP not to repeat it (which is good). You did very good by explaining the removal of the tag in the edit summary which is visible to the OP and anyone else looking at the revisions.

##### Further notes:

The correct place to guide users on how to use a tag is in the tag's excerpt. That's the short guidance message appearing while you apply tags to a question:

[image]

The sad truth is that most users don't bother to read that. That can be evident by many tags being misused and the extreme cases of meta- or soon-to-be-burninated- tags which literally have *"DO NOT USE"* in their guidance and they are still being applied.

All this goes to show that in the end we are limited with handling misuse of tags. The only things us caring curators of the site can do is watch and add tags to custom filters so we can retag them appropriately. Watching a tag will make it more visible on your homepage, while creating a custom filter will even show you a little red dot next to it indicating there are new questions for you to check.